# Matlab two different colors in same line in legend

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, printf, legend-properties

In Matlab, the following generates a black color on the specified line in the legend:

```
leftAxis = sprintf('left y-axis','Color','r');
leg = legend([.. bla bla ..], sprintf('test [%s]', leftAxis), etc... );
```

What I'm trying to achieve is two colors on the same line in the legend.
(so in this example the part *'test'* should be black and the part *'left y-axis'* should be red.

What I've tried:

- Doing the above: no result.
- Getting the string arguments from the legend and altering the color: colors the whole line.
- Using LaTeX to color the text: no result.

A picture to visualise what I mean:

[image]

Comment: Could you add an image of the desired result?

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin: of course. Give me a minute

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin I got what he wants… after re-reading the text twice or more hhehe. He wants a part of the text to be black, and the other red, as in html: `Test <font color='red'>[Name]</font>.` Jean, correct me if I am wrong…

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin: Werner understands what I mean. Please take a look at my updated question for a visualisation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably you mistyped tex string:

```
figure
hold on
line1H=plot(1:10,1:10);
line2H=plot(1:10,2*(1:10),'r');

leg{1} = 'BlackText {\color{blue}line1} BlackAgain';
leg{2} = 'BlackText {\color{red}line2} BlackAgain';

legend([line1H,line2H],leg{:})
```

Generates:

[image: Colored Legend]

Comment: I used LaTeX in a different way (didn't know you could do it this easy) so that  might explain it. Thank you for your help: it works!

Answer (score 3):

I am going to be blunt and guess that you made a mistake.

Here we can see that [latex should work in figure labels](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/21984).

And here we can see that [matlab should allow using colors with latex](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/112287).

Unfortunately I don't have the chance to try it out now, but I would guess this is the way to go. If it fails, please show what code you used.